# Getting dataTable selected records as JSON formatted data using angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Have datatable and selecting multiple records across multiple pages and trying to convert all selected records data as JSON data structure. I tried below code and getting JSON data and also two extra fields, could you please help me how to remove `"check":true,"checked":true` in json data.

```
 fnGetJsonData(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.persons.filter(f => f.checked)));
 }
```

output:

```
[{"id":860,"firstName":"Superman","lastName":"Yoda","dropdown":"yuvi","check":true,"checked":true}]
```

expected JSON data:

```
[{"id":860,"firstName":"Superman","lastName":"Yoda","dropdown":"yuvi"]
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drop-down-population-mra1xy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array.map()

```
const data = this.persons.filter(f => f.checked);

const mappedData = data.map(d => ({id: d.id, firstName: d.firstName, lastName: d.lastName, dropdown: d.dropdown});

console.log(mappedData);
```

Comment: Hi @Adil Khalil, Could you please suggest me the below question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67549092/how-to-update-the-params-for-every-pagination-button-clicks?noredirect=1#comment119430695_67549092

Comment: If this answer was helpful, I will appreciate if you can accept it as an answer.

Comment: Yes , done. That's helped me a lot. If possible could you pls help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67549092/how-to-update-the-params-for-every-pagination-button-clicks