# How to Update the params for every pagination button clicks

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datatables, angular-datatables

Trying to implement pagination, Initially I'm trying to load datatable with few records, once page loaded trying to click pagination buttons like `next or any pagination buttons` to update the new set of records. I'm able to get the  `iStart, iEnd` records but unable to update the `url` for every pagination click. Trying to print the `console` but function is not calling and `console.log` is not updated with new params. Could you please suggest me how to do the update the params for `API`. Here is the sample code,

Sample Demo datatatble is not work with pagination, for verification printing the `console` for the updated querystring.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        
        this.dtOptions = {
          processing: true,
          destroy: true,
          columns: [
            { title: '<input type="checkbox" />' },
            { data: 'index' },
            { data: 'firstname' },
            { data: 'lastname' }
          ],
          infoCallback: (oSettings, iStart, iEnd, iMax, iTotal, sPre) => {
              pageStartNo = iStart;
              pageEndNo = iEnd;
              console.log(pageStartNo, pageEndNo);
              // this.loadTable();
          }
        };
      }
    loadTable(){
        let params = new HttpParams()
          .set('param1', '123')
          .set('param2', '456')
          .set('minNumber', pageStartNo) 
          .set('maxNumber', pageEndNo);
    
        console.log('params >>>>>>>>>>>>>' + params.toString());
    
        this.http
          .get<any[]>(
            'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/master/demo/src/data/data.json',
            {
              params
            }
          )
          .subscribe(response => {
            this.persons = response.data;
            this.dtTrigger.next();
          });
      }
```

HTML code:

```
<button (click)="loadTable()">Load Table</button>
```

[Sample Demo Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/passing-pagination-params-and-draw-the-table)

Comment: I think you need here ajax in dataOption  object to callback api again for new set of records

Comment: Hi, If possible ping me sample code for reference ?

Comment: Can you explain more about your use-case and where in which part of your code you got stuck in stackblitz ?

Comment: Tried with Ajax property, now pagination, search, paginations are not supporting and not able to populate the table with below stackblitz, '''https://stackblitz.com/edit/passing-pagination-params-and-draw-the-table-ew5wgn'''

Comment: Then I think ajax property will not work for you at this use-case. What will you want in your stackblitz shared by you in question ?

Comment: For avoiding performance issues..I'm trying to load few records at initialisation time, once table loaded and click on pagination button like Next button another set of records can be loaded. This case is failing, here unable to pass start and end params to the API. Please consider console.log message for latest query string. Example table  is just for clicking pagination button for population updated console.log message. Please suggest me how to update params to the API for every button click.

Comment: but at first is your api supports pagination ?

Comment: No...for now it's not working...is it possible to add default start and end records for first time initialisation table and after that pagination click to update ?

Comment: let me check out

Comment: Sure, @GaurangDhorda thanks, please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you wanted to apply server-side pagination right?

Here is an [official documentation](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way) for this.

Add ajax method in `dtOptions`.

```js
this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 10,
  serverSide: true,
  processing: true,
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
    console.log('Params', dataTablesParameters);
    //If you have different key for page number/size change it
    dataTablesParameters.minNumber = dataTablesParameters.start + 1;
    dataTablesParameters.maxNumber =
          dataTablesParameters.start + dataTablesParameters.length;    this.http
      .post<any[]>(
        'YOUR_API_NAME_HERE',
        dataTablesParameters,
        {}
      )
      .subscribe(resp => {
        this.persons = resp.data;

        //Once API fetched data successfully inform datatable by invoking the callback
        callback({
          recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
          recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
          data: []
        });
      });
  },
  columns: [{ data: 'id' }, { data: 'firstName' }, { data: 'lastName' }]
};
```

[Working Stackbliz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatable-server-side)

Comment: Thanks Sameer for the help, I saw the response like "'''{"draw":2,"recordsTotal":258,"recordsFiltered":258,"data":[{"''' here "draw" key is increasing every click, could you please help me how to pass this param to API from UI code ?

Comment: I think `draw` is how many times the table has loaded/drawn, also I have already added code on how to send params. Could you please tell what your API expects as param like `pageNumber` and `pageSize`

Comment: HI Sammer, Actually I need to pass few more params to the API for getting the data, like below `dataTablesParameters.startRow = dataTablesParameters.start + 1;
dataTablesParameters.endRow = dataTablesParameters.start + dataTablesParameters.length;               
dataTablesParameters.param1=123;
dataTablesParameters.param2=456;
dataTablesParameters.param3="DEC-20";'`  and sample API is `/api/testAPI?param1=123&param2=456&param3=DEC-20&startRow=1&endRow=1`, but getting data as `null`, is this the correct format the pass the `params`, pls suggest...

Comment: Try to debug your API,  Check your API what params it needs and check the request payload in the network tab of chrome whether you are sending all the required params.

Comment: Also, there are multiple ways to send params, Sending params object like in this answer, or using `HttpParams` or directly concatenating in the API URL